# How to display PDF document from stream using web Browser control

Tags: winforms, pdf, webbrowser-control

I've been trying to display the PDF Document i saved in my SQL Database and preview it without having to save it.
I want use the web Browser control to display the PDF from stream. Someone recommended PDFium but i dont know how to use that so i stick with this one. Hope someone can help me get it work

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = bh_imu\\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = bh; Integrated Security = True"))
            {
                dt.Clear();
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from documents where docname like '%" + listBox1.SelectedItem + "%' ";
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                labelDname.Text = r["designername"].ToString();
                labelUnitName.Text = r["unit"].ToString();
                labelTeam.Text = r["team"].ToString();
                labelSite.Text = r["sites"].ToString();
                //labeldocType.Text = r["doctype"].ToString();
                labelDocname.Text = r["docname"].ToString();
```

I named the Column in my table containing the PDF with doc. And i created it with the datatype of Varbinary(max). and here is how i tried to display it.

```
 string fileName = Path.GetFileName(r["doc"].ToString());
                byte[] buff = null;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
                buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buff);
                webBrowser1.DocumentStream = stream;
                webBrowser1.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I choosed a different PDFviewer called Apitron which is not openSource but it solved my problem.

I added PDFViewer component for APITRON.RESTERISER first, which suits my .NET Framework.

It is as simple as this.

```
byte[] data = null;
data = (byte[])r["doc"];   

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(data);
  memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //Buffer:Byte[]; Offset:Int; Count:Int.  
  memStream.Position = 0;
  pdfViewer1.Document = new Document(memStream);
```